# Subscribe http.post that is placed inside a promise Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, firebase-authentication, observable

It gets complicated to me when I mix the promise with subscribe and another async task together.

This is my auth service:

```
getCurrentUserToken(){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
      firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ true).then(function(idToken) {
        resolve(idToken)
      }).catch(function(error) {
        reject(error)
      });
    }) 
  }
```

This is my HTTP service:

```
sendEmail(email) {

    return this.authService.getCurrentUserToken().then(token => {
      const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Basic server-Password',
        })
      };
      let data = email
      data['idToken'] = token
      return this.http.post(this.apiServer + 'sendEmail', data, httpOptions)
    })

  }
```

This is how I call the `sendEmail(email)` function at the component:

```
    Observable.fromPromise(this.httpService.sendEmail(element)).subscribe(
      data3 => {
        console.log(data3)

      }, error => {
        console.log(error)
      }
    ))
```

I have to pass currentUserToken to the API to let the API authenticate the user session. Still, both of the the `getCurrentUserToken()` `sendEmail()` are running in async, so I have to use `Promise` to pass the `Token` to `sendEmail()` function, and let the sendEmail function to call the API to send the email.

Without the promise, I am able to subscribe to the `http.post` like this:

```
this.httpService.sendEmail(element).subscribe(
          data3 => {
            console.log(data3)

          }, error => {
            console.log(error)
          }
        ))
```

Unfortunately, I screwed it up when I added the promise into it, and the console.log is returning this:
`Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}`

Please advise on how to subscribe to the `http.post` that is placed inside the `Promise`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's seriously no need of Complicating things here.

I'll use `async`/`await` syntax here and for that, we'll have to work with `Promise`s instead of `Observable`s. Good thing is, we can leverage the `toPromise()` method on an `Observable` value to change it to a `Promise`

### Focus on my comments in the code as well

#### Here's the implementation

For `getCurrentUserToken`

```
getCurrentUserToken() {
  return firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true);
  // This will already return a Promise<string>
  // So no need to do a .then and then return from there.
}
```

#### For `sendEmail`

```
async sendEmail(email) {
  // Since getCurrentUserToken returns a Promise<string> we can await it
  const token = await this.authService.getCurrentUserToken();
  // token will now have the Current User Token
  const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Basic server-Password',
    })
  };
  let data = email
  data['idToken'] = token
  return this.http.post(this.apiServer + 'sendEmail', data, httpOptions).toPromise();
  // Notice how we're calling the .toPromise() method here 
  // to change Observable into a Promise
}
```

#### How to use it?

This code will go in your Component Method where you were previously calling `this.httpService.sendEmail`. **DO MAKE SURE TO MARK THAT FUNCTION AS `async` THOUGH.**

```
// We can only await something in a function which is declared of type async
async sendEmail() {
  try {
    const data = await this.httpService.sendEmail(element);
    // Since sendEmail again returns a Promise, I can await it.
    console.log(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i have some question at the final part. Do i have to wrap the entire `try catch` with another async code or the `try catch` is the wrapper for the `await sendEmail()` ?

Comment: I've updated my answer to clarify your doubt. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't we use Observable instead of Promises here.

```
    getCurrentUserToken() {
    return new Observable(obs => {
      firebase
        .auth()
        .currentUser.getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ true)
        .then(function(idToken) {
          obs.next(idToken);
          obs.complete();
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          obs.error(error);
        });
     });
    }

    sendEmail(email): Observable {
     return new Observable(obs => {
      this.authService.getCurrentUserToken().subscribe(token => {
        const httpOptions = {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: 'Basic server-Password'
          })
        };
        let data = email;
        data['idToken'] = token;
        this.http
          .post(this.apiServer + 'sendEmail', data, httpOptions)
          .subscribe(
            result => {
              obs.next(result);
              obs.complete();
            },
            error => {
              obs.error();
            }
          );
      });
     });
    }

     // now call the service from Component like this.
     this.httpService.sendEmail(element).subscribe(
      data3 => {
        console.log(data3)

      }, error => {
        console.log(error)
      }
     ));
```

Comment: `subscribe` inside `subscribe` is an anti-pattern called "callback hell",
you may use flattening operators like `switchMap`/`mergeMap` to fix this issue

Comment: You may want to use promises where two or more calls are needed to resolve one object. You can't operate on part of the data, without the other, therefore you need promises and Promise.all.